# How to write a test case for input changes in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Hi I am developing an application using Angular and TypeScript.

Following is the template code:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search Results" (input)="searchInput($event)">
```

and my typescript code regarding searchInput method is :

```
searchInput(event: Event & { target: HTMLInputElement}) {
   const { value } = event.target;
   this.value = value;
    // calling other method to reset values
  }
```

I was wondering the how to write input test cases in my spec.ts file.

```
describe('Component', () => {
  let component: Component;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<Component>;
  const event = Event; // Is this fine ?
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
          AppModule
      ],
      providers: [
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Component);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('searchInput() ', () => {
    // how to approach 
  });
});
```

Please provide a way how I will approach for writing test cases.

Comment: you can take a look @ this repo and check the spec files it very basic but will help you i guess https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/AngularConcepts

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it does not solve my problem.

Comment: @Vaibhav What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am still finding a way, i am a newbi. If you have any idea please suggest.

Comment: If I were you, the only thing I would do is `expect(component.value).toEqual(/*your value*/);` (of course, call `component.searchInput()` before)

Comment: Thanks for the approach. Just a little help how i will get /*your value*/ from Event ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way of writing a simple test case.

What it does:

1. Creates the component
2. Checks that the default value for `value` is falsy
3. Finds the HTML input element by CSS (you might need to be more specific here, depending on your template)
4. Set's the `value` of the input element and dispatches an `input event`
5. Makes sure that the value of `value` has been updated correctly

**Code** (remember to import `By`):

```
...    

import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

...

it('searchInput should update value when input changes', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);

    expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.value).toBeFalsy()

    const el: HTMLInputElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input')).nativeElement;
    const testValue = 'some_value';

    el.value = testValue;
    el.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));

    expect(fixture.componentInstance.value).toEqual(testValue);
}));
```

Comment: This is what i am looking for thank for the code. If possible can you please provide some links to understand the jasmin test language. So that i will get a good clarity on how to use.

Comment: @Vaibhav happy to help! Have you tried the official guide on anglar.io? I thinks that's a great resource to start with: https://angular.io/guide/testing

Comment: Thanks for the link and help.

Comment: `el.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));` saved me! :) thanks!